# Jasper report data summary

Tags: filter, jasper-reports, summary

I am trying to create a report to display a summary of the values of the columns for each row.   A basic analogy would an inventory listing.  Say I have about 15 locations like 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B, 3C etc.   Each location has a variety of items and the items each have a specific set of common descriptions, i.e. a rating of 1-9, Boolean Y or N, another Boolean Y or N.  It looks something like this:

```
2A   4       Y       N
2A   5       Y       Y
2A   5       N       Y
2A   6       N       N      
...
2B   4       N       Y  
2B   4       Y       Y      
...etc.
```

What I would like to produce is a list of locations and summary counts of each attribute:

```
Location    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9      Y  N        Y N      TOTAL
2A                1 2 1            2  2        2 2        4
2B                2                1  1        2          2
...
___________________________________________________________
Totals            3 2 1            3  3        4 2        6
```

The query returns fields:

```
location_cd String  
desc_cd Int 
y_n_1 String 
y_n_2 String
```

I have tried grouping by location but cannot get the summaries to work.   I tried putting it in a table but that would only take the original query.  I tried to create datasets for each unit and create variables in each one for each of the criteria but that hasn't worked yet either.  But maybe I am way off track and crosstabs would work better?  I tried that and got a total mess the first time.  Maybe a bunch of subreports?

Can someone point me in the correct direction please?    It seemed easy when I started out but now I am getting nowhere.  I can get the report to print out the raw data but all I need are totals for each column broken down out by location.

Comment: are you using any RDBMS ?

Comment: Sybase ASE/15.7.0.  I am using Jasper Studio 5.5.1 to create my reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer required me to group by location_cd and create variables to sum the occurances of the desc_cd values(1-9)

```
$F{desc_cd}==1?1:0
```

etc. for 2-9.    Reset type was by group.  Same for the Y/N columns.

```
$F{y_n_1}.equals("Y")?1:0
```

Instead of putting them in the details row I put the text fields in the group footer, put some column titles in the column header and the rest in the page header.

I still need to find a way to sub-group some of my groups but that is for another question.