# Jasper Subtotal

Tags: jasper-reports, subtotal

I have a report- from another question: [Jasper report data summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280293/jasper-report-data-summary) which shows totals for a number of columns by location.   I need to sub-total some of the location_cds and am not sure where to start.  I have one group - by location_cd.  Some location_cds have sub-locations, i.e. 3A has 3A1, 3A2, 3A3.   Right now I have the totals for each individual row displayed in the group footer.  I would like to see a subtotal for any location_cd that has sub-locations.  I am trying to puzzle out how I am going to approach that.  Should I see if I can do that in the query or will Jasper help me out here?

I am querying Sybase ASE 15.7.0 and am using Jasper Studio 5.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub totals are the same as totals, just check the following:

1. add the order by corresponding to your list - usually add the item to the order by list

   ORDER BY some_name_wharever, my_subtotal_thing_to_be_ordered
2. create a new group using the wizard, right click the root of the report on the report inspector and select "add report group"
3. create a new variable just like the total one but mind the reset and increment group

That should do it. Hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

I feel like you are trying to create a crosstab, with different subtotals and a general total... Do try looking into crosstabs.. they may be tricky to use, but the end result is great if used properly!

Comment: The need of subtotals in groups does not mean you need to build a crosstab, that's overkill.